# Where can I find a table/list of all/many languages' plural/singular forms for hours/time?

Tags: english, grammar, swedish

Even though I'm natively Swedish, I'm seriously unsure if it's "1,1 timme" or "1,1 timmar". That is, what in English would be "1.1 hour" or "1.1 hours".

Even as I'm typing this, I'm unsure if it's "hour" or "hours" when it's neither exactly 1 or over 1.

I've struggled with this in both English and my native language all my life. I don't know what it is. This particular piece of information is either never clearly explained, ambiguous, or it doesn't stick in my brain for whatever reason.

Is there a clear, authoritative, free online resource where this is clearly laid out in a big table, per-language?

I frequently have similar concerns and wish I could "look up" things which just aren't words in dictionaries. Basically, "grammar rules". But the only things I can find are *extremely* massive and impossible-to-digest computer files from "ICU" or similar organizations, where I would spend countless hours trying to interpret their data format which seems to be intended for computer programs/parsers rather than human beings.

Comment: +1 since I wanna know more here too. (Not sure in German either, whether it's 1.1 (eins komma eine) Stunde or 1.1 (eins komma eins) Stunden, and so on.) While the whole number compound (one-point-one or one-and-a-half etc) is clearly "more than 1" (-> not singular), the last pronounced element of it is singular, which I guess is the reason for why speakers use both. Also, "1001 nights" is "1001 night" in German.

Comment: It may be a very unsatisfying opinion, but IMHO, if you are a native Swedish speaker and you don't know whether "1,1 timme" or "1,1 timmar" is correct, then it means there's no such rule to favor one over the other in Swedish - unless you include arbitrary stylistic rules conjured up by scholars or tradition.  "Do native speakers find X acceptable?" is the only valid test for deciding whether X is grammatical or not.